# Java Embedded Database For a Few Computer Access

Tags: java, embedded-database

I just wonder if i can(or is it a good way to use it) set location of an embedded database on a server computer and run my desktop app on a computer which have access to server folders and get/insert data from   database?

For example, i have one server machine and 3 computers accessing it. I want them to insert/update data of server database which is installed as embedded style.

If i can't which method is easier and free way of doing it?

***EDIT:*** Actually that server is a not server.. it is just a computer others can access to.

Comment: If you have a server, why not to install some not embedded database?

Comment: Embedded dbs are easier to implement,install and  faster to deal with problems.

Comment: Are you sure that you understand what *embedded* db is? And well server is just a computer. :)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_database  Your answer is here =) Yeah it is a computer but mine just gives folder access nothing more so it does not act as server

Comment: If you install some db to it, it will act as a sever. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't a good idea to share the embedded database's files between different applications. For most embedded database implementations it is even not possible, because the embedded database engine needs exclusive access to the underlying data files. Furthermore it is a performance penalty to access the database files over a shared folder.

I know only two databases allowing shared database file access: SQLite and MS Access. Java and MS Access is not a good combination. Avoid it, use it only if you are forced to. For SQLite I don't know if it performs well for different processes on the same machine. But over a shared folder, I think this would work only for the simplest cases.

So if you have multiple client applications accessing the same database then you should install a database server. A database server is exactly made for such a sceanario. It manages the server local database files efficiently and can handle many clients at the same time. There are simple ones like Apache Derby or H2 which are Java only implementations and very easy to use. If you need more performance then you can go with MySQL or PostgreSQL, but these are more complex to administer.

Answer (score 0):

The word "embedded" normally means running inside a given JVM. To access it from clients, as opposed to from other code running in the same JVM, an method of connecting will need to be supplied, such as a connection protocol + port. Well, by the time you do all that, you have in fact rolled your own server.

If you just want filesystem access, well normally databases lock the files they're using. And if they don't, you will anyway be missing all of the control and ACID constraints that a database normally gives you.

Answer (score 0):

[H2 database](http://www.h2database.com) can be run in different [modes](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#connection_modes): embedded, in-memory, standalone and mixed.
I think you are asking about the last one "mixed" mode.